# Reset Tensorflow engine between implementations/models?

Tags: tensorflow.js

Edit: I've added a repo to reproduce the issue:
https://github.com/bengfarrell/tf-issue-tester

I have a single page application that uses both Posenet and FaceAPI (https://github.com/justadudewhohacks/face-api.js) in 2 different views.

Separately (when in diff demo applications), those two views work perfectly, however just importing the models in those 2 different view components while in the same application, it breaks.

My first indication that something is wrong is the warning:

```
engine.ts:224 webgl backend was already registered. Reusing existing backend factory.
t.registerBackend @ engine.ts:224
(anonymous) @ backend_webgl.ts:2801
engine.ts:224 cpu backend was already registered. Reusing existing backend factory.
```

But the real problem is that when running FaceAPI, I get the error:

```
engine.ts:583 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: t is not a function
at engine.ts:583
at engine.ts:423
at t.scopedRun (engine.ts:434)
at t.tidy (engine.ts:421)
at l (engine.ts:583)
```

I'm running under the assumption that the Posenet environment is not compatible with the FaceAPI environment somehow. Ideally I'd like to clean up TFJS and start fresh with each of the 2 component views.

I've looked at the docs and tried to run `engine.dispose()` and `engine.disposeVariables()` prior to running the FaceAPI implementation, but I'm not having luck.

Does anyone have any pointers on how to properly clean up between TFJS usages? I should also probably ask for strategies on ES6 imports. Perhaps there are ways to import that don't actually create the underlying factories that the warnings are referencing. If not, I can certainly get creative with other loading strategies such as dynamic imports or appending non-module based scripts on demand to the DOM.

For reference, my imports are:

```
import {load, getAdjacentKeyPoints} from '@tensorflow-models/posenet';
```

and

```
import {nets, loadFaceLandmarkModel, TinyFaceDetectorOptions, detectSingleFace} from 'face-api.js';
```

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please share your code ?

Comment: Sure, I thought it might be a bit much to share (it's a semi-large project). But I was able to distill the error down in a much simpler demo. Thanks for looking! https://github.com/bengfarrell/tf-issue-tester